# New server setup steps

Tags: linux, security, ssh

I'm interested in the steps you make when you need to set up a new Linux (preferably CentOS) server, putting a emphasis on security, like changing SSH port, limiting root SSH access, etc.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/247402/locking-down-a-box-on-the-internet/247419#247419

Comment: This question is far too broad, even for general best-practices. The link Zoredache posted is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't change SSH port, because it complicates setups (now I should remember which port I use on which server and I have 20+ of them) and confuses me and my customers. I use [DenyHosts](http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/epel-i386/denyhosts-2.6-5.el5.noarch.rpm.html) instead, it is available from an EPEL repo. It's also good to disable password-based authentication in favor of key-based in `sshd_config` (`PasswordAuthentication no` and `PubkeyAuthentication yes`), at least for the `root` account (`PermitRootLogin without-password`). Of course empty passwords should be disabled, but I think it's a default setting nowadays (`PermitEmptyPasswords no`).

Comment: thanks for the tip. any other steps? :)